# Exercise on Orientation k-forms

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms

This question comes out of the book I have been using to study k-manifolds.

"Consider the helicoid in $R^3$ parametrized as **X**($u_1,u_2$)=($u_1 $cos($3u_2)$,$u_1 $sin($3u_2)$, $5u_2$)

Where ($u_1,u_2$) $\epsilon$ [$0,5$] x [$0$, $2$$\pi$]

Let S denote the underlying surface of the helicoid and let $\Omega$ be the orientation 2-form defined in terms of **X** as:

$$\Omega_{X(u_1,u_2)}(\mathbf a,\mathbf b)=\det\begin{bmatrix}
    -5\sin(3u_2) & a_1 & b_1 \\
    5\cos(3u_2) & a_2 & b_2 \\
    -3u_1 & a_3 & b_3 
    \end{bmatrix},$$

where $\mathbf a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\mathbf b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ are within the linear span of the tangent vectors to the coordinate curves, **T$_{u1}$** and **T$_{u2}$**"

It was established that the tangent vectors and the parametrization **X** were incompatible with $\Omega$:

($\Omega$(**T$_{u1}$**,**T$_{u2})$**<$0$).

The exercise asks us to:

"Modify **X** to one having the same underlying surface of S but that is compatible with $\Omega$ "

This is where I am having some difficulties. Anytime I try to modify the parametrization I keep finding that $\Omega$<$0$. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formatting for the determinant of the matrix went wrong. I apologize for that.

Comment: You need to learn some basic MathJax. :) I partially fixed it.  So did you put in $\mathbf T_{u_1}$ and $\mathbf T_{u_2}$ explicitly? I can't follow what you actually did. The obvious way to try modifying the parametrization is to switch the order of $u_1$ and $u_2$. Also, I do not believe your first column is correct. Where did you get it?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I plugged in the tangent vectors for vectors a and b. I also revised the first column of the matrix.

Comment: So what do you get when you use $\mathbf a = \mathbf T_{u_1}$, and $\mathbf b = \mathbf T_{u_2}$?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin You find that X is incompatible with the orientation k-form. To modify the parametrization, I tried switching the order of $u_1$ and $u_2$. This would just mean switching the order of the tangent vectors in the matrix determinant, right? In other words, letting a=T$u_2$ and b=T$u_1$ .